# How can I prevent git bash vi from crashing while rewording commit message with interactive rebase?

Tags: bash, git, crash, rebase, vi

I am getting the below error message while attempting to reword a commit in git bash using vi/vim. I have tried on IntelliJ terminal and Git Bash terminal itself with the same result.

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Program is `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`.

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

I want to reword the commit message of `hash1`

```
git log
---

commit <hash1>
  # ...

commit <hash2>
  # ...
```

I use `git rebase -i` to attempt. Git opens `vi` so I can specify the rebase options. I press `i` to enter `insert` mode, type 'reword', and then press `ctrl+c` to enter `command` mode. I press `:wq` to save and quit.

```
git rebase -i <hash2>
---

reword <hash2> <message>
```

Git opens COMMIT_EDITMSG in `vi`. I press `i` to enter `insert` mode. I type the new message. I press `ctrl+c` to enter `command` mode and -- instead of entering command mode, `vi` crashes.

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I have tried the following `git config --global core.editor` settings recommended in a similar SO post:

- `null`
- `vi`
- `vi -f`
- `vim`
- `vim -f`

I *am* able to recover using `vi .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` and restoring the `swp` file, but I shouldn't *have to*. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer in saving me from having to use notepad++ as my editor.

Comment: Use `escape` instead of `Ctrl+C`? I don't know how Git+Bash (Windows) works but `Ctrl+C` could have sent an interrupt signal to the editor.